# After keying value in animation track, property becomes locked and can't be changed

Tags: animation, godot

I am trying to rotate a sword hitbox around the player depending on which animation is currently playing.

I have the following node setup:

```
Scene
|---AnimationPlayer
|---Marker2D
.....|---Area2D
..........|---CollisionShape2D
```

The CollisionShape2D is for the shape of the hitbox. The Marker 2D is centred on the player, and I want to use its rotation property to rotate the hitbox around the player.

So I go to my AnimationPlayer node, select an animation and key the rotation property at the start of the animation.

The issue is that once I have keyed rotation to the first animation, the rotation property becomes "locked" and I cannot change its value anymore.

Is this intended behaviour and I am missing something obvious? Or is this a bug?

I am using Godot version 4.0.beta16

Comment: This seems to happen if the Update mode for the animation track of the Marker2D rotation property is set to continuous.

If I change the Update mode to discreet then this issue disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by having an `AnimationTree` set to *Active*. Deactivate the tree and the issue disappears.

Alternatively, change the `update mode` of the animation track to *discreet* (from *continuous*) then this issue also disappears.

See: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/74006